# ad hoc build and signer not valid issue

Tags: xcode, build, adhoc

I am trying to make an ad hoc build, but I get this "the signer is not valid" error when people try to sync my app to their ipad.  I'm getting confused because I look around and there is mention of this "Entitlements.plist" file that is not mentioned at all on this page in the provisioning portal:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/distribution.action

Do I have the wrong how-to page?  I followed that page correctly, I thought, but am having a hard time testing what exactly is wrong because on my ipads I get this team provisioning profile which seems to make everything work ok (I can't get the error).  Could the problem be that in my Target's GetInfo I had the Code Signing Identity's "Any iOS Device" field set to iPhone Developer and not to the Ad Hoc Provision item?

Or do I need this entitlements plist file that isn't mentioned in the link above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct regarding the code signing identity.

The team provisioning profile makes everything work only on the development devices. Ad-Hoc builds require an Ad-Hoc distribution profile instead for signing.

Make sure in the configuration for creating ad-hoc builds to choose the "iPhone distribution" certificate for "Code Signing Identity" instead of the "iPhone developer" certificate.